# Working with iPhone microphone programmatically

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, microphone

I'm developing an iPhone 3.1 application.

I want control by voice a text. If a person blows over microphone, the text will appear. If that person is blowing strong the text will appear quickly, but if he is faintly blowing the text will appear slowly.

I want to control if there is a sound over microphone, and the volume (high or low).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is this of any use?

> A simple class for listening to
>   microphone levels, suitable for the
>   iPhone.

Here is the link:
https://github.com/stephencelis/sc_listener

Comment: And this one, too! http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/